# Need database design advise

Tags: mysql, database-design

I attached the DB schema, so it will be simple.

Problem: Need to get the `item` records from the company e.g. 'A'.

Should I add to the `item` table `company_id` field? 
Will it be a redundancy info as we can always take it using `user_company` ?

Thank you in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal preference, I would advice you not to add `company_id` in `item` table, as this will reduce the purpose of `user_company` table and both the Id will be repeated in `Item` table, of no use.

For retrieving  `item` records from the company e.g. 'A'. Simple join can be used.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not add it as this will create redundant data and unneeded foreign keys. As Vijayp mentioned, this would make the user_company table less functional in its current setup. It would be poor schema design, aside from any preference, to implement what you have suggested.

The following example would be a way to get the data (used for simplicity, not the best way to write the query necessarily):

`SELECT * FROM item i, user_company uc, company c 
 WHERE i.creator_user_company_id = uc.id AND uc.id = c.id`

Comment: Don't use of *, Add column name you want to fetch in select query.

Comment: @vijayp As I mentioned, the example was simple for clarity's sake since the question did not list any other actual fields aside from the ID columns.

Comment: agree with you.